# Why can't I see my Hardrive for my compaq mini 110c from A windows Xp installation on usb stick?

Tags: windows-xp, usb, installation, usb-flash-drive, compaq-laptop

I have windows xp installation files on a USB drive using wintoflash. I've downloaded mass storage driverpack and slipstreamed them into the install. when the bootup begins I press f6 at the appropriate screen to enable sata drivers for my harddrive. Then it comes to the partition/harddrive selection screen, I only see my usb flash stick. I'm at my wits end with this problem. I need to install xp.

Comment: Molly, I did everything you mentioned in # 2 before asking the question and my bios won't allow me to change the controller. I think I could borrow a friends usb floppy drive.

Answer (score 1):

well, F6 only supports the driver installation via floppy disk, two options:

1. attach a USB floppy drive
2. slipstream the controller driver into your XP installation CD (e.g. with **[nLite](http://www.nliteos.com/)**) and then transfer it to USB with WinToFlash.

not familiar with the Compaq Mini 110, but can you change the controller mode from AHCI to IDE in the BIOS?